# Why is GPU render time inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm building a WebGL application using THREE and am noticing some odd timing on the GPU. I don't have repro code available at the moment but I thought I'd ask the question in case it's a known browser quirk or something common and fixable.

#### Scene Setup

- Scene with ~2,000,000 polygons, 136 Meshes, and 568 Object3D instances.
- Using THREE.Composer with the FXAA and Unreal Bloom passes.
- Using THREE.OrbitControls.
- The scene is only rendered when something is known to have changed. For example, a draw is scheduled when the user drags the scene to move the camera with the controls or something in the scene moves. The scene is often static so we try not to render unnecessarily in those cases.

#### The Problem

The issue happens when the scene has been static (not drawn for a bit) and then the user changes the camera position by dragging. Once the user starts dragging the framerate is very choppy -- maybe 10-20 fps or lower -- for several frames before smoothing back out to something closer to 60. This happens consistently when leaving the scene alone for several seconds and then dragging again. If the mouse is dragged consistently after the initial stutter then the framerate stays smooth. Nothing different is being rendered for these frames.

This stuttering doesn't happen and the scene remains snappy if it's rendered every frame using `requestAnimationFrame`.

Here's the performance profiler with the stutter when the scene is only being rendered when something changes. You can see that there is a lot more time spent on the GPU during the frames that stutter before smoothing out again:

[image]

And the profiler when the scene is rendered at 60 fps:

[image]

Any thoughts? Why is there so much more GPU work happening suddenly on drag? Could the draw be blocked by some other rendering process? Why would it happen so consistently after not rendering for a few seconds? I've profiled using the latest version of Chrome but the stutter is present in Firefox, as well.

Thank you!

Comment: I've done several projects where I skip rendering when not needed, and it always picks up right where it left off at 60FPS, so it's not a problem with Three.js. How are you pausing your rendering? Are you just using `return` in your `requestAnimationFrame` loop? Are you removing any event listeners and then re-adding them?

Comment: I only schedule the draw using `requestAnimationFrame` when the scene is known to have changed so there's no need to return early in the render function. If a draw has already been scheduled when a change happens then another draw is _not_ scheduled.

That means there is nothing happening at all in javascript when the user isn't interacting with the canvas. I haven't tried just letting the render loop spin with an early return but I could try that, too.

Comment: I'd have to see your code to pinpoint if that's the exact reason, but I think something simple in your render loop like: `if(!needsToRender){return null;}` should perform pretty well because you're not adding/removing event listeners. I understand the desire to completely stop JavaScript from doing anything in the background, but calling a function that only checks a boolean 60 times per second is insignificant.

Comment: I added something similar to what you mentioned and while it happens less often the odd stutter still occurs at times. You're right that adding an empty function call is pretty light-weight but I'm hesitant to add it without understanding _why_ it addresses the issue (which it doesn't seem to solve entirely). This also isn't the only javascript running on the page so I'd prefer not adding it at all if possible. Why would having an empty requestAnimationFrame call be better than none? When I get a chance I'll try to produce a repro case so it's easier to show the issue. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

without a live sample there is no easy way to know BUT....

## 1 Three.js can do frustum culling on objects.

That means if some objects are off outside of the view they won't get drawn. So, put the camera in such a way that all objects are visible will run slower than if only some objects are visible

## 2 Primitive Clipping

Same as above except at the GPU level. The GPU clips primitives (it doesn't draw or compute pixels outside the view) so similar to above, if the lots of the things you're trying to draw happen to be outside the view it will run faster than if everything is inside the view.

## 3 Depth(Z) Buffer rejection

Similar to above again, if your objects are opaque then if a pixel is is behind an existing pixel via the depth test the GPU will skip calling the pixel shader if it can. This means if you draw 568 things and the first one you draw is the closest thing to the camera and covers up many things behind it than it will run faster than if all those things behind it draw drawn first. Three.js has the option to sort before drawing. Usually sorting is turned on for transparency since transparent objects need to be drawn back to front. For opaque objects though drawing front to back will be faster if any front objects occlude objects further back.

## 4 Drawing too many frames?

Another question is how are you queuing your draws? ideally you only queue a single draw and until the drawing has happened don't queue any more.

So

```
// bad
someElement.addEventListener('mousemove', render);
```

The code above will try to render for every mouse move even if that's > 60 fps

```
// bad
someElement.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
});
```

The code above may queue up lots and lots of requestAnimationFrames all of which will get executed on the next frame, drawing your scene multiple times per frame

```
// good?
let frameQueued = false;

function requestFrame() {
  if (!frameQueued) {
    frameQueued = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
}

function render(time) {
  frameQueued = false;
  ...
}      


someElement.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  requestFrame();
});
```

Or something along those lines so that at most you only queue on render and don't queue any more until that render has completed. The code above is just one example of a way to structure your code so that you don't draw more frames than you need to.

Comment: Hey gman, thanks for the thorough response! I've taken a look at these and I don't believe any of them are the problem. What's throwing me is that it stutters for the first few frames and then smooths out even though it's drawing all the same geometry (the camera is pulled back and always contains the full scene). It'll take me a bit to pull together a repro I can share but I'll try to do that when I get a chance.

Comment: Something I noticed is that if the window is smaller then the stuttering doesn't happen. Since the composer and unreal bloom pass all create render targets based on the size of the canvas, there's a bit of texture memory involved. I'm not all that familiar with webGL implementations but could it have anything to do with the GPU trying to reallocate that texture memory after it hasn't been used for a bit? It couldn't be a pixel fill issue because the framerate is smooths out after wiggling the view for a few frames.